# Keep Getting IndexOutOfRange

Tags: c#

I'm creating a program that holds three arrays: one for the person's last name, one for the points scored and one for the player number. Now, Ive got all the arrays and everything done but when I try to call my ProcessDelete method I keep getting

System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Any help would be appreciated

```
     static  Int32[] ProcessDelete(Int32[] playerNumbers, ref Int32 playerCount, String[] playerLastName, Int32[] playerPoints )
    {
        Int32[] newArray = new Int32[playerNumbers.Length - 1]; String[] newArray2 = new String[playerLastName.Length - 1]; Int32[] newArray3 = new Int32[playerPoints.Length - 1];

        int index = 0;
        int index2 = 0;
        int index3 = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        int t = 0;
        while (index < playerNumbers.Length)
        {
            if (index != playerCount)
            {
                newArray[j] = playerNumbers[index];
                j++;
            }

            index++;
        }

        while (index2 < playerLastName.Length)
        {
            if (index2 != playerCount)
            {
                newArray2[k] = playerLastName[index2];
                k++;
            }

            index2++;
        }
          while (index3 < playerLastName.Length)
        {
            if (index3 != playerCount)
            {
                newArray3[t] = playerPoints[index3];
                t++;
            }

            index3++;
        }
        return newArray;          
    }

    static void DeletePlayer(Int32[] playerNumbers, String[] playerLastName, Int32[] playerPoints, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
    {
        int player;// Player number to delete
        int playerindex;//index of the player number in Array
        if (playerCount < MAXPLAYERS)
        {

            player = GetPositiveInteger("\nDelete Player: please enter the player's number");
            playerindex = GetPlayerIndex(player, playerNumbers, playerCount);


           if (playerindex != -1)
            {

                {

                    Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: Number - {0}, Name - {1}, Points - {2}", playerNumbers[playerindex], playerLastName[playerindex], playerPoints[playerindex]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Succesfully Deleted");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    ProcessDelete(playerNumbers, ref playerCount, playerLastName, playerPoints);
                }
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: player not found");
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: the roster is empty");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: didn't someone ask a very similar question yesterday?

Comment: If you look at the stack trace for the exception, it will tell you exactly where the exception is occurring. If you run the code in the debugger, the debugger will not just show you where the exception occurs, but also will allow you to actually _look_ at the variable that's out of range. If once you know exactly where and how the exception is occurring, you still don't know how to fix the problem, then you can update the question with the specifics, explaining the precise problem you're having.

Comment: If you comment out the call to `ProcessDelete`, does the application not throw the error? Also what values of `player` and `playerindex` are generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your third loop you have:

```
newArray3[t] = playerPoints[index2];
k++;
```

It should be:

```
newArray3[t] = playerPoints[index3];
t++;
```

Comment: In the same place, index2 is being used and should be index3.  Probably there should only be one loop though.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Right, the use of `index2` is probably the reason for the error message, increasing `k` instead of `t` would just throw away all items except the last. Using one loop for the three arrays would be better, but perhaps one array of objects containing three properties would be best.